# WPF SkiaSharp Canvas Click Mouse position

Tags: c#, wpf, skiasharp

Note:  This is a C# SkiaSharp WPF application.

When I repaint my `SKCanvas` (which is the full width of my app), I record the width and height.  Ignore height for now.  On a 4K monitor the width is recorded correctly 3840 pixels (when maximised).

When I click on the canvas far left, the mouse X position recorded is almost zero as expected.

However, when I click on the far right of the canvas 2552 is given as the X position, not something near 3840 as I expected?

This is the code I use to get the mouse position when it is clicked.

```
private void MyCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var pixelPosition = e.GetPosition(sender as SKElement);
    // ...
}
```

and my XAML:

```
<skia:SKElement
    Name="MyCanvas"
    PaintSurface="MyCanvas_PaintSurface"
    MouseLeftButtonDown="MyCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown"
    />
```

I also checked the width/height in the `SizeChanged` event of `MyCanvas` and that does NOT report 3840 either, it reports 2552 as the width?

Any ideas why the reported width is 2552 whereas the actual width is 3840?

Comment: Sounds like the monitor is configured at 150% scale.

Comment: You are correct.  Now I need to work out how to find that out in my App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Leandro pointed out your DPI scaling is 150%. You can get the DPI scale in *.NET Framework >= 4.6.2* and *.NET Core >= 3.0* with the [`GetDpi`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getdpi?view=netcore-3.1) method of `VisualTreeHelper`. It returns a [`DpiScale`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dpiscale?view=netcore-3.1) struct that contains the scale horizontal and vertical DPI scale factors.

```
private void MyCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   var mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
   var dpiScale = VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(mainWindow);

   var dpiScaleX = dpiScale.DpiScaleX;
   var dpiScaleY = dpiScale.DpiScaleY;

   var pixelPosition = e.GetPosition(sender as Canvas);
   var scaledPixelPosition = new System.Windows.Point(pixelPosition.X * dpiScaleX, pixelPosition.Y * dpiScaleY);

   // ...your code.
}
```

If you are working with a lower version of a framework without `GetDpi`, you can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jaimer/getting-system-dpi-in-wpf-app) instead.

```
var mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;

Matrix m = PresentationSource.FromVisual(mainWindow).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;
var dpiScaleX = m.M11;
var dpiScaleY = m.M22;
```